# What class would be good for a magician/trickster character?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, rogue, bard

I'm relatively new to DND-5e and want to make a magician/trickster character. I'd prefer this character to rely mostly on illusions, slight of hand, and trickery rather than pure magic. My DM recommended playing a Bard (college of glamour) or a Rogue (arcane trickster).

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, and welcome. This site is more about specific question rather than general opinions. If you are asking the pros and cons of each class for your specific case, that is fine in this site (I think). Just clarify a bit with a small edit. And, things like starting level and level that might end the campaign are useful to narrow it more.

Answer (score 4):

Without getting into the details of the classes, here are a few subclass descriptions that may be what you are looking for:

#### [Arcane Trickster Rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#ArcaneTrickster) (PHB, pg. 97)

> Some rogues enhance their fine-honed skills of stealth and agility with magic, learning tricks of enchantment and illusion. These rogues include pickpockets and burglars, but also pranksters, mischief-makers, and a significant number of adventurers.

This is probably the canonical answer to the question. It has many features that synergize magic and roguish play. It also has tremendous flexibility in that the spells learned come from the Wizard spell list.

The main drawback is the the Arcane Trickster is a 1/3 caster, so the spells known and spell slots are pretty limited compared to the other two subclasses on this list. (13 spells known, 4/3/3/1 slots at 20th level.)

#### [Trickery Domain Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#TrickeryDomain) (PHB, pg. 56)

> Gods of trickery — such as Tymora, Beshaba, Olidammara, the Traveler, Garl Glittergold, and Loki — are mischief-makers and instigators who stand as a constant challenge to the accepted order among both gods and mortals. They’re patrons of thieves, scoundrels, gamblers, rebels, and liberators. Their clerics are a disruptive force in the world, puncturing pride, mocking tyrants, stealing from the rich, freeing captives, and flouting hollow traditions. They prefer subterfuge, pranks, deception, and theft rather than direct confrontation.

The Trickery Cleric benefits greatly from being a *full caster*, and the domain spells given all contribute significantly to the playstyle outlined in your question. The main drawback here is essentially that it lacks all of the generic class features of the Rogue class.

#### [Bardic College of Whispers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofWhispers) (XGtE, pg. 16)

> Most folk are happy to welcome a bard into their midst. Bards of the College of Whispers use this to their advantage. They appear to be like other bards, sharing news, singing songs, and telling tales to the audiences they gather. In truth, the College of Whispers teaches its students that they are wolves among sheep. These bards use their knowledge and magic to uncover secrets and turn them against others through extortion and threats.
>
> Many other bards hate the College of Whispers, viewing it as a parasite that uses a bard’s reputation to acquire wealth and power. For this reason, members of this college rarely reveal their true nature. They typically claim to follow some other college, or they keep their actual calling secret in order to infiltrate and exploit royal courts and other settings of power.

The class features here have little to do with illusion and more to do with social manipulations, but the Bard as a full caster has the flexibility to pick up many illusion spells. For a list of Illusion school spells already on the Bard spell list, see [this filtered list at DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/school/illusion?filter-class=1&filter-search=&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=&filter-partnered-content=f). Additionally, with the Bard's Magical Secrets at 10th, 14th, and 18th levels, you can take *any* spells you like from any spell list, enhancing the flexibility even further.

Comment: Actually, this helped a lot! I really like the idea of a Trickery Domain Cleric and I think I'll make my character one. Thanks :)

Comment: This good answer could be improved by covering Illusionist wizards.